# php session expiring early

Tags: php, session

Php session is expiring after logging . This happens when i put the project in server but while i working in localhost this problem not occurs.

That is ,after i login the page using username and password i am not able to click any menu while i clicking any menu it rollback to the login page. this problem is occur in server only it works perfectly in localhost.

```
function test_input($data)
{
    trim($data);
    stripslashes($data);
    htmlspecialchars($data);
    mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}






if(empty($_POST['txtname']))
{
     $usererr="Valid username required!";
}
else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/',$_POST['txtname']))
{
     $usererr="Invalid charactors found!";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['txtname'])>=10)
{
    $usererr="Overlimit of username charactors!";
}
else
{
    test_input($_POST['txtname']);
}


if(empty($_POST['txtpass']))
{
    $passerr="Valid Password required!";
}
else if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/',$_POST['txtpass']))
{
    $passerr="Invalid charactors found!";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['txtpass'])>=10)
{
    echo "Overlimit of password charactors!";
}
else
{
        test_input($_POST['txtpass']);
}



    $uname=@mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtname']);
    $pass=@mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);


    $uname1=md5($uname);

    $pass1=md5($pass);

    //echo"$uname1"."<br/>"."$pass1";


    $rs=@mysql_query("select * from salve_admin where Name='".$uname1."' and Pass='".$pass1."' ");

    if(@mysql_num_rows($rs)==1)
    {

        $rs1=@mysql_fetch_object($rs);

        $_SESSION['user']=$rs1->Name;


    }


}
```

Comment: on each `php` page add `session_start();` on top of page just after starting `<?php`. also please stop using deprecated+removed  `mysql_*` version. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` (latest version). add some `error reporting code` too to get all possible errors

Comment: Do not use `@` unless you exactly know what you are doing. The stfu operator is in 99,9% of all cases unnecessary and blocks error reporting.

Comment: sorry i didnt mentioned here i used session start and php tag already